# AWS Quicksight/SQL Query for timestamp monthly data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

so I'm pretty new to Quicksight, trying to get a dataset together.

I have a SQL Table of logins as a data source, and each row has an id, timestamp and user_id.

Similar to this:

| id | timestamp | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01T15:17:13.000Z | 234 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02T15:17:13.000Z | 235 |

I want to build a dataset that shows an aggregate of logins by year. So something like

| Year | Active Users in January | Logins in January |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | 500 | 10000 |
| 2020 | 600 | 10002 |

Essentially, the active users would be grouping the rows of logins by user_id, and the logins would just aggregate the timestamps by month.

Is this kind of view something I could provide in a QuickSight dataset, given the login table i would have? or even just with a raw SQL query?

my thought would be this would be easier if I could embed SQL queries into quicksight's calculated fields syntax, but I don't believe that is possible. Even then, I'm not sure How to do this in just SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon QuickSight, `Extract` returns a specified portion of a date value. Requesting a time-related portion of a date that doesn't contain time information returns 0.

When you create a dataset or prepare your data for use in an analysis, you can customize the data in the query editor.

```
SELECT EXTRACT([Timestamp]), COUNT(user_id), COUNT([Timestamp]) user_id
FROM Logins
group by year([Timestamp])
```

To create a basic SQL query

Create a new data source and validate the connection.

Fill in the options necessary to connection, however you don't need to select a schema or a table.

Choose Use custom SQL.

(Optional) You can enter your query in the SQL editor, or continue on to the next step to use the full-screen version. To enter it now, create a name for the query. Then type or paste a SQL query into the editor. The SQL editor offers syntax highlighting, basic autocomplete, autoindent, and line numbering.

Choose Edit/Preview data. The full query editor appears with the SQL editor displayed. The query is processed and a sample of the query results displays in the data preview pane. You can make changes to the SQL and confirm them by choosing Apply. When you are done with the SQL, choose Close to continue.

At the top, enter a name for the dataset. Then choose Save & visualize.